# Convert time data into human readable time using PHP

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I have a time value in the following data format:

```
"2020-08-05T11:45:10.3159677Z"
```

How do I convert it to something human readable, like as follows, using PHP?

```
Wednesday, August 5, 2020, 11:45 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo date("H:i A, F jS, Y", strtotime("2020-08-05T11:45:10.3159677Z"));
```